# Что лучше - закавычить двусмысленное слово или заменить его?

Tags: выбор-слов

> Азоло славен тем, что здесь была заточена королева Венеции.

Речь о слове "славен".

Comment: «...королева Венеции»? Серьёзно? Тоже в кавычки.

Comment: Ну вот, и прок от тебя случается. *Последнее государство крестоносцев становится колонией Венеции. В компенсацию Катерине выделяют синьорию Азоло, в области Венето. Вскоре Азоло становится культурным центром. Здесь Катерина провела свои последние годы жизни до смерти в 1510 году.* Предложу автору кавычки, но етая Кэт правит синьорией Азоло... Чем не крулева?

Comment: Синьория - форма правления, при которой гражданская и военная власть сосредоточена в руках единоличного правителя - синьора (или синьоры). При этом синьор пр получении власти от предшественника получал от папы титул викария. Викарий - это не король. И вообще - не любая верховная власть - королевская

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь вполне можно увидеть не "дурную славу", а исторически обусловленную приобщённость данной местности к монаршей особе. Поэтому двусмысленность не мешает - разве что потомкам бедняжки (если они есть) или фанатичным монархистам.

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта возможны.

1) Азоло известен тем.... Нейтральный вариант.

2) Азоло "славен" тем... Здесь автор ироничен и более интересен.

Кавычки нужны, так как в обычном смысле слава должна быть положительной.

СЛАВНЫЙ, 2. обычно кратк. чем. Ставший известным, прославившийся. Край с. своими традициями. Город славен живописными садами и парками. Село славно своими кружевницами.